# syslog-ng not filtering on tags on remote server

Tags: nginx, logging, filter, tags, syslog-ng

I have an `nginx` server using `syslog-ng` to send access and error logs to a remote `syslog-ng` server. I am having it tag the messages so that the remote server can filter on the tags to put them into files. But the filter statements seem to be not working.  On the local client I did a test, sending the messages to a local file using the filters and they work there. But they seem to break somehow when being sent remote.

The config on the client is:

```
@version: 3.13
@include "scl.conf"

## global options.
options { chain_hostnames(off);
  flush_lines(0);
  use_dns(no);
  use_fqdn(no);
  owner("root");
  group("adm");
  perm(0640);
  stats_freq(0);
  bad_hostname("^gconfd$");
};
source s_qa_nginx_access {
    file("/var/log/nginx/access.log" follow-freq(1)
    tags("qa_nginx_access")
    flags(no-parse));
    };
source s_qa_nginx_error {
    file("/var/log/nginx/error.log" follow-freq(1)
    tags("qa_nginx_error")
    flags(no-parse));
    };
destination d_syslog-ng_central { syslog("10.0.0.50" transport("tcp") port(514)); };
log { source(s_qa_nginx_access); destination(d_syslog-ng_central);};
log { source(s_qa_nginx_error); destination(d_syslog-ng_central);};
```

On the remote `syslog-ng` server I have

```
@version: 3.13
@include "scl.conf"
options {
  flush_lines(0);
  use_dns(no);
  use_fqdn(no);
  owner("root");
  group("adm");
  perm(0640);
  stats_freq(0);
  bad_hostname("^gconfd$");
  time-reap(30);
  mark-freq(10);
  keep-hostname(yes);
};
source s_network { syslog(transport(tcp) port(514)); };
filter f_qa_nginx_access { tags("qa_nginx_access"); }; 
filter f_qa_nginx_error { tags("qa_nginx_error"); }; 
destination d_qa_nginx_access {
  file(
    "/var/log/remote/qa_nginx_access.log"
    owner("root")
    group("adm")
    perm(0640)
    );
  };
destination d_qa_nginx_error {
  file(
    "/var/log/remote/qa_nginx_error.log"
    owner("root")
    group("adm")
    perm(0640)
    );
  };
log { source(s_network); filter(f_qa_nginx_access); destination(d_qa_nginx_access); };
log { source(s_network); filter(f_qa_nginx_error); destination(d_qa_nginx_error); };
```

If I remove the filter from the log statement all of the log messages go to both files. but with the filter in place nothing makes it to any of the files on the remote server. Is it somehow not sending the tags to remote?

Comment: According to the syslog-ng documentation it seems the "Tags are available locally, that is, if you add tags to a message on the client, these tags will not be available on the server." Looks like I can't filter on server using tags created on the client. There must be another way to this

Answer (score 0):

You might want to refer to syslog-ng administration guide. Below are some of the important notes from the guide. If you need to send the tags remotely, use SDATA.meta.tags instead or you can use the template to write is as part of the message too.

Full admin guide can be find at the following link:
https://www.syslog-ng.com/technical-documents/doc/syslog-ng-open-source-edition/3.22/administration-guide/58

- **Tags are available locally**, that is, if you add tags to a message on the client, these tags will not be available on the server.
- To include the tags in the message, use the ${TAGS} macro in a template. Alternatively, if you are using the IETF-syslog message format, you can include the ${TAGS} macro in the .SDATA.meta part of the message. Note that the ${TAGS} macro is available only in syslog-ng OSE 3.1.1 and later.